# Add to cart the selected product when button clicks

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add the price, name,... to cart that is generated dynamically on html. Before i want to get those values to that button. But is not getting me. Here is code

But I have various categories

```js
        var b,c,d;
                function add(){
                    for(var i=0;i<1;i++){
                    b=document.getElementsByTagName("span")[i];
                    c=document.getElementsByTagName("p")[i];
                    d=document.getElementByTagName("h4")[i];
                    alert(b.textContent);
                    alert(c.textContent); 
                    alert(d.textContent)};
                }
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-9">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <h5></h5>
                            <img  src="defaultimg.png">
                            <span></span>
                            <p></p>
                            <button value="Add to Wishlist" onclick="add()">Add to Wishlist</button>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                        
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <img  src="defaultimg.png">
                            <span></span>
                            <p></p>
                            <h5></h5>
                            <button value="Add to Wishlist" onclick="add()">Add to Wishlist</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <h1></h1>
                            <h2></h2>
                            <h3></h3>
                            <h4></h4>
                            <button value="Add to Wishlist">Add to Wishlist</button>               
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I am able to get only single value that is first one whenever I click button in any div using strictly javascript

Answer (score 0):

Open your console, it will say :

```
Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementByTagName is not a function(…)
```

You have a typo, you're missing a `s`.

```
d=document.getElementsByTagName("h4")[i];
```

It breaks your code at the end of loop 1, which is why you get only one value.

This being said, since you have only one `<h4>` tag, not sure that JS will be happy with `d = document.getElementsByTagName("h4")[1];` (Trying to select the second `<h4>`, which does not exist). It may return `undefined`, and your code will break again when you try `d.textContent`, you'll get `Cannot access method textContent of undefined.` So even after fixing the typo, I believe the code will break after loop 1 for another reason.

Bottom line, I'm not sure you will ever retrieve all your values with this code, it's way too frail and breaks way too easily. You should try and find another way.

Comment: Thank You @Jeremy Thille. I have get those by reading those values manually by getting their id.